# TFSPreview email notification on check-in

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

How do I setup an email notification on TFSPreview?

I want to get an email for each check-in

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access to Alert Email on Team

[image]

And once there you can select what you want alerts by and enter your email address.

[image]

Comment: What mail server is it using? I've done it, but not getting any emails

Comment: @Ido you can adjsut in your administration console your server adress

Comment: hi i also did the same,but i did't get any mail,could you please help me!

Answer (score 1):

Check this topic regarding the request. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc507647.aspx
Here you can find all the info you need. =)

Answer (score 0):

Check official document from microsoft TFS 2017 through browser

[email notification setting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/alerts-and-notifications?view=tfs-2017)